# Getting a tzinfo object from a timestamp

Tags: python, datetime

I have a timestamp in this format: `Fri, 2 Jan 2015 11:44:17 -0800`.  I extract the time/date using datetime, but I want to put the timezone in a tzinfo object.  What's a quick way to extract just the timezone from a timestamp like this one, into tzinfo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pip install python-dateutil`

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse("Fri, 2 Jan 2015 11:44:17 -0800")
datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 2, 11, 44, 17, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -28800))
```

Comment: Eric, please consider adding more detail to your answer. I'm sure it's pretty self explanatory to you, but that would be helpful for beginners. :)

Comment: @Eric - This is great, but there's one issue.  `ERROR:aclass:afunction invalid: Missing tzinfo.`  That's after doing: `our_dt = our_dt.replace(tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -28800))`  type(our_dt.tzinfo) is `<class 'dateutil.tz.tzoffset'>` -- how can I get it to be the right type?

Comment: @Eric - Further, doing it your way gives the error: `'tzoffset' object has no attribute 'zone'`

Comment: @horsehair: are these errors coming from within `dateutil.parse`? Or is the rest of your application unable to deal with the type of the result?

Comment: @Eric - It's the rest of the application.  I think what it comes down to is, I need to convert the tzinfo to a pytz compatible one.  Is that possible?

Comment: @horsehair: Thought that might be the case. I have no idea how to do that conversion...